# Cash flow of longevity Bonds

Tags: bond

For a longevity Bond, how is the cash flow and how can I replicate it? I am confused with the cash flow. An Investor pays a principal and receive coupon payment depends on the longevity of certain selected population? So if the selected population lives longer, one would expect a higher coupon payment? How about the principal? Is it similar to CAT bond that the principal is then forgiven?

Comment: I think you are right on all of these points (as far as I know).

Comment: @AlexC Is the principal also forgiven? I just know in CAT bond the principal is forgiven if the catastrophe occurs. How would I measure here if the event occured or not? Is there a threshold for the ages of the underlying population?